# Using JPA mapping for complex queries

Tags: jpa

I have following entities

- Employees : id, empId, fname, lastName, age
- EmployeeAttendence: id, empid (FK), date, subjectId(FK), wasPresent
- Subject : id, subjectName

Query required:
-For all employees between age 30 and 40, find if they were present between date d1 and d2, for subjectId = 5.
If employee was not present then record must be existing in op retult but with empty attence redord

Is there value in using JPA for such type of things? Or should i jut use plain SQL.

Comment: What JPQL have you tried?

Comment: I am modeling my data store as of now. So  was wondering if mapping my entities relations really provides me some value or should i not do that. Any advice?

Comment: when you've tried to create the JPQL for that you will see whether it is capable or not, and whether it is benefitting you using JPA. That is how you learn. This site is for solving specific problems not opinion-based answers on whether someone thinks something

Comment: @user93796 - Could you please share the model classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are a little bit confused why JPA is useful.

The benefit you are getting from JPA is that you'll have a lot of functionalities which will help you to **modify the data** within your database. You'll get concurrency control options (explicit locking/implicit locking/optimistic/pessimistic locking), dirty checking mechanism, caching, dynamic updates, transparent JDBC batching and much more.

**For reading the data**, of course you could use your entities but this is only applicable for simple use-cases. When performance is also a consideration from your side and a little bit more complex queries, then you have the option to use JPQL and if that's not possible then native SQL.
For reading I prefer using DTO projections as it has a huge performance impact compared to using pure entities.

For more reading:

https://blog.arnoldgalovics.com/using-projections-in-your-data-access-layer/
https://blog.arnoldgalovics.com/how-much-projections-can-help/